# using an isolated database like django models

Tags: python, django

I have a database (postgresql) which is not created by django models (orm).
Now I need to use that database in my django project. I can write raw sql to retrieve data from database. But I do want to fetch data like I do with django models. How can I do that?

here is my databse settings:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
     'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
     'NAME': 'doe_geodash_metadata',
     'USER': 'dev',
     'PASSWORD': '123456',
     'HOST' : '172.16.0.150',
     'PORT' : '5432',
 },
'datastore' : {
    'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
    'NAME': 'doe_geodash_data',
    'USER' : 'dev',
    'PASSWORD' : 'dev',
    'HOST' : '172.16.0.150',
    'PORT' : '5432',
}
```

}

here I wrote necessary models (orm) for 'default'. Its working fine. But for the  second one ('datastore') there is no models and I have created some geometric tables from other application(geoserver). This 'datastore' database is used by geoserver. But now I need to query over some geometric tables on 'datastore' database. I ran python **manage.py inspectdb** but it does not shows anything for the 'datastore' database tables.

Any help please.

Comment: Are you looking to automatically generate the django models that you would use for ORM? If so, I think you want inspectdb. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/legacy-databases/

Comment: No, I want to work without generating models.

Comment: @cjahangir you can't. You need a python object to map to a database row, which is what a Django Model is.

Answer (score 1):

use `python manage.py inspectdb` will print to you what objects in your existing database.

If you want to officially save it into models use:

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

for more details read here: [Using legacy database with django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/legacy-databases/)

Comment: @cjahangir how will ORM map your statements to valid SQL?